# How to break an association arrow three times

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-uml

Look at this class diagram

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \umlclass[]{ApplicationController}
    {
        - application\_service: ApplicationService \\
        - issuer\_service: IssuerService \\
        - authorization\_handler: AuthorizationHandler \\
        - verification\_handler: VerificationHandler \\
        - did\_method\_handler: DidMethodHandler
    }
    {
        + handleApplicationReadRequest() \\
        + handleApplicationWrite()
    }

    \umlclass[below=0.8cm of ApplicationController]{ApplicationService}{}
    {
        + read() \\
        + write(data: str)
    }

    \umlclass[below=0.8cm of ApplicationService]{IssuerService}{}{}

    \umlclass[right=3.2cm of ApplicationController]{VerificationHandler}{}{}

    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm2=-5cm]{ApplicationController}{ApplicationService}
    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm2=-5cm]{ApplicationController}{IssuerService}

    \umlclass[below=1cm of VerificationHandler]{DidMethodHandler}{}{}

    \umlclass[below=1cm of DidMethodHandler]{AuthorizationHandler}{}{}

    \umlinterface[below=1cm of AuthorizationHandler]{SignatureVerificationStrategy}{}
    {
        + execute(p: ProofDTO, ...)
    }

    \umlclass[below=1cm of SignatureVerificationStrategy]{JwsVerificationStrategy}{}
    {
        + execute(p: JwsProofDTO, ...)
    }

    \umlimpl{JwsVerificationStrategy}{SignatureVerificationStrategy}

    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm1=3cm]{ApplicationController}{VerificationHandler}
    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm1=5cm]{ApplicationController}{DidMethodHandler}
    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm1=5cm]{ApplicationController}{AuthorizationHandler}
    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm1=5cm]{ApplicationController}{SignatureVerificationStrategy}


    \umlclass[below=0.8cm of IssuerService]{IssuerRepository}{}{}
    \umlclass[below=0.8cm of IssuerRepository]{CryptoMaterialRepository}{}{}

    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm2=4cm]{IssuerService}{IssuerRepository}

    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm1=3cm, arm2=-5cm]{VerificationHandler}{CryptoMaterialRepository}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

I need the association between `VerificationHandler` and `CryptoMaterialRepository` to not go under the `JwsVerificationStrategy` class. I'm unable to break the arrow three times and I don't even know if it is possible using `tikzuml`

[image]

Comment: What about to increase the distance to the box above of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tikz-uml` diagram is a regular TikZ picture with a number of predefined UML styles for boxes and arrows. Apart from those styles you can also use standard TikZ drawing commands for situations where the predefined styles are not sufficient.

In this case you can draw a path using `\path` that goes around the *JwsVerificationStrategy* box. This can be done relatively easily using the `calc` tikzlibrary. This library introduces the syntax `($(node)+(x,y)$)` that specifies the coordinate resulting from adding `x,y` to the node. Paths furthermore use line specifications `-|` and `|-` for *horizontal, then vertical* and *vertical, then horizontal* respectively.

Now the path is *VerificationHandler horizontal vertical (JwsVerificationStrategy+right,down) horizontal (JwsVerificationStrategy+left,down) vertical horizontal CryptoMaterialRepository*. In code:

`\path[draw,-angle 45] (VerificationHandler) -| ($(JwsVerificationStrategy)+(3,-1.5)$) -- ($(JwsVerificationStrategy)+(-4,-1.5)$) |- (CryptoMaterialRepository);`

Full MWE (note that I removed some unnecessary packages):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage[left=1cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \umlclass[]{ApplicationController}
    {
        - application\_service: ApplicationService \\
        - issuer\_service: IssuerService \\
        - authorization\_handler: AuthorizationHandler \\
        - verification\_handler: VerificationHandler \\
        - did\_method\_handler: DidMethodHandler
    }
    {
        + handleApplicationReadRequest() \\
        + handleApplicationWrite()
    }

    \umlclass[below=0.8cm of ApplicationController]{ApplicationService}{}
    {
        + read() \\
        + write(data: str)
    }

    \umlclass[below=0.8cm of ApplicationService]{IssuerService}{}{}

    \umlclass[right=3.2cm of ApplicationController]{VerificationHandler}{}{}

    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm2=-5cm]{ApplicationController}{ApplicationService}
    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm2=-5cm]{ApplicationController}{IssuerService}

    \umlclass[below=1cm of VerificationHandler]{DidMethodHandler}{}{}

    \umlclass[below=1cm of DidMethodHandler]{AuthorizationHandler}{}{}

    \umlinterface[below=1cm of AuthorizationHandler]{SignatureVerificationStrategy}{}
    {
        + execute(p: ProofDTO, ...)
    }

    \umlclass[below=1cm of SignatureVerificationStrategy]{JwsVerificationStrategy}{}
    {
        + execute(p: JwsProofDTO, ...)
    }

    \umlimpl{JwsVerificationStrategy}{SignatureVerificationStrategy}

    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm1=3cm]{ApplicationController}{VerificationHandler}
    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm1=5cm]{ApplicationController}{DidMethodHandler}
    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm1=5cm]{ApplicationController}{AuthorizationHandler}
    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm1=5cm]{ApplicationController}{SignatureVerificationStrategy}


    \umlclass[below=0.8cm of IssuerService]{IssuerRepository}{}{}
    \umlclass[below=0.8cm of IssuerRepository]{CryptoMaterialRepository}{}{}

    \umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm2=4cm]{IssuerService}{IssuerRepository}

    %\umluniassoc[geometry=-|-, arm1=3cm, arm2=-5cm]{VerificationHandler}{CryptoMaterialRepository}
    \path[draw,-angle 45] (VerificationHandler) -| ($(JwsVerificationStrategy)+(3,-1.5)$) -- ($(JwsVerificationStrategy)+(-4,-1.5)$) |- (CryptoMaterialRepository);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]